# pmatrix and superscript

Tags: matrices, superscripts

I would like to place a superscript to a pmatrix, but the superscript is not correctly positioned.

```
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}^{T}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks OK to me but you can shift it to the left with some negative space `{\!\!T}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the reasons why I always use (square) brackets for delimiting matrices is that the larger the matrices are, the fatter the parentheses become.

Compare the two results, one with `pmatrix`, the other with `bmatrix`:

[image]

The parentheses don't add to clarity, only to the required space.

One might argue that the "T" is too far also in the second case, but I don't think so. The following shows the result with

```
^{\!\!T}
```

after the `pmatrix` and

```
^{\!T}
```

after the `bmatrix` (which I believe is overkerning):

[image]

A problem with `pmatrix` is that the backup depends on the size of the matrix: `\!\!` would probably be too much for a 2-by-2 matrix.